# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF Error

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Getting this error when trying to insert a value to a table.
the table was created using the below script:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Audit_PatientControlledSubstanceAgreement](
    [PatientID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [UsersID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [DateAdded] [date] NOT NULL,
    [FileName] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [FilePath] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [FileType] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [NextScheduledDate] [date] NULL,
    [CreateDT] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [AgreementType] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Deleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Audit_PatientControlledSubstanceAgreement] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
```

I've even tried to change IDENTITY_INSERT to ON but still getting the same error. I'm using the below code to insert the item to the table:`

```
    var Audit_PatientControlledSubstanceAgreement = new Audit_PatientControlledSubstanceAgreement
                            {
                                CreateDT = DateTime.Now,
                                Deleted = true,
                                AgreementType = model.AgreementType,
                                DateAdded = model.DateAdded,
                                FileName = model.FileName,
                                FilePath = model.FilePath,
                                FileType = model.FileType,
                                NextScheduledDate = model.NextScheduledDate,
                                PatientID = model.PatientID,
                                UsersID = model.UsersID
                            };

                            db.Audit_PatientControlledSubstanceAgreement.Add(Audit_PatientControlledSubstanceAgreement);
                            db.SaveChanges();
```

`

Comment: In your code you do not specify a value for ID, do you?

Comment: no I'm not specifying value for ID but still getting the exception.

Comment: What is the class definition of `Audit_PatientControlledSubstanceAgreement `? And is it a code-first EF model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line above the `Id`:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

Like this

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```